# Convert Python list of dicts into Postgresql array of json

Tags: python, json, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to insert a Python(2.7) list of jsonb elements into a Postgresql(9.4) table with a column of datatype: jsonb[].

Here's some code:

```
import json
anArray = [{"name":"Joe","age":51,"yob":1964,"gender":"male"},{"name":"George","age":41,"dob":1974,"gender":"male"},{"name":"Nick","age":31,"dob":1984,"gender":"male"}]
myArray = []
#here's what I have so far: 
for e in anArray:
    myArray.append(json.dumps(e))
#this gives me
myArray = ['{"name":"Joe","age":51,"yob":1964,"gender":"male"}','{"name":"George","age":41,"dob":1974,"gender":"male"}','{"name":"Nick","age":31,"dob":1984,"gender":"male"}']
#insert commands
insert_sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (data) VALUES (%s);"
insert_data = (myArray, )
cursor.execute(insert_sql, insert_data)
```

Now when I try to insert myArray, psycopg2 gives me an error

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "data" is of type jsonb[] but expression is of type text[]
```

I'm not quite sure what the correct syntax is to insert this data into the table. Any help/pointers will be appreciated.

**Solution**
Thanks to piro, it was a quick solution.

```
insert_sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (columns) VALUES (%s::jsonb[]);"
insert_data = (myArray, )
cursor.execute(insert_sql, insert_data)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a psycopg error: it is a PostgreSQL error psycopg is just relying.

The error seems suggesting there is no implicit text[]->jsonb[] cast so you need to add a manual one:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (columns) VALUES (%s::jsonb[]);
```

Comment: Well then... That worked like a charm. Thanks so much @piro !

Comment: I tried this, but it creates an empty json that cannot be inserted:   `'''{}'''`  `DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.`

Answer (score 6):

Use [Psycopg JSON adaptation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#json-adaptation)

```
from psycopg2.extras import Json

data = [
    {"name":"Joe","age":51,"yob":1964,"gender":"male"},
    {"name":"George","age":41,"dob":1974,"gender":"male"},
    {"name":"Nick","age":31,"dob":1984,"gender":"male"}
]

query = '''
    insert into t (j)
    select array_agg(j)
    from jsonb_array_elements(%s) s(j)
'''

cursor.execute(query, (Json(data),))
```

`jsonb_array_elements` will return a set of `jsonb` which will be turned into an array of `jsonb` by `array_agg`

Comment: This is the best solution.